# How to initialize Vector<double> from DenseVector in Math.NET?

Tags: c#, math.net

Latest version (3.13) of Math.Net fails to run the following C# code:

```
Vector<double> a;
Vector<double> b = new DenseVector(a);
```

it shows the following error message:

```
cannot convert from 'MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector<double>' to 'MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Storage.DenseVectorStorage<double>'
```

Please suggest a good replacement for this initialization? and if possible explain why it works with previous versions of Math.NET but not with 3.13.

Answer (score 1):

This has not worked with previous versions either.

If what you're looking for is for `b` to be a clone of `a`, you can use `Vector<double> b = a.Clone();`